# Defining field in instance variable causes all instances field to be the same

Tags: c++

***Disclaimer: I'm just now learning C++. Also, I wasn't quite sure how to phrase the title of the question. My apologies.***

**Problem:**
All of the instances of GAChromosome in the "chromosomes" vector end up with the same genes as the last GAChromosome instance pushed back to the vector despite them being initialized with different genes.

**Question:**
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
string generateRandomGenes(int theLength)
{
    string genes = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < theLength; i++)
    {
        int index = (rand() % kCharacterSet.length());
        genes += kCharacterSet[index];
    }

    return genes;
}

GAPopulation::GAPopulation(int thePopulationSize, string theTargetGenes)
{
    targetGenes = theTargetGenes;
    chromosomes = vector<GAChromosome *>(thePopulationSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < thePopulationSize; i++)
    {
        // These genes are different every time, which is correct.
        string genes = generateRandomGenes((int)targetGenes.length());

        GAChromosome * chromosome = new GAChromosome(genes);
        chromosome->setFitness(calculateFitness(chromosome));
        chromosomes.push_back(chromosome);

        delete chromosome;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thePopulationSize; i++)
        // Every instance has the same set of genes as the last chromosome inserted, which is incorrect.
        printf("%s\n", chromosomes.at(i)->getGenes().c_str());
}
```

I really don't understand why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: >> I'm just now learning C++.
If you are a beginner, it is better to stay away from `new`. It is a low level expert only tool (usually used only by infrastructure library writers) in c++ unlike other languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

You allocate memory for `chromosome`, push the *pointer* into the vector, and then delete (free) the memory pointed to by `chromosome`. That freeing of memory make *all* pointers to the memory invalid, including the ones in the vector.

---

It might be easier to understand pointers with some illustrations.

When you allocate the memory, it looks something like this

```
+------------+      +---------------------------+
| chromosome | ---> | memory you have allocated |
+------------+      +---------------------------+
```

After you push the pointer into the vector, you now have to pointer to the vector:

```
+------------+     
| chromosome | ---------\
+------------+           \     +---------------------------+
                          >--> | memory you have allocated |
+-------------------+    /     +---------------------------+
| pointer in vector | --/
+-------------------+
```

And finally, when you free the memory, it looks something like this

```
+------------+     
| chromosome | ---------\
+------------+           \     +-----+
                          >--> | ??? |
+-------------------+    /     +-----+
| pointer in vector | --/
+-------------------+
```

Where `???` represents the now unallocated memory.

What *probably* happens in reality, is that the system reuses the same memory for the next allocation you make, and so the next pointer assigned to `chromosome` is actually pointing to the same memory, and you overwrite the previous memory with the new data.

After the creation loop ends, the memory doesn't actually cease to exist, and its contents will be the last data you wrote into that memory, leading to the behavior you see.

The solution to this is very simple: ***Don't*** use pointers. In modern C++ there is seldom a need for pointers any more. Instead store *values* in the vector, actual object instances, e.g.

```
vector<GAChromosome> chromosomes;
```

Note: If `GAChromosome` contains comples data, then you should also learn about the [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: And if he really has a reason to use pointers he should at least use a [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), especially if he's still learning.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Maybe... it depends. I advise people to look at the new smart pointers as a way to hold *ownership*. Can a resource be owned by one a single entity at a time then use `std::unique_ptr`, or if a resource can be owned by multiple entities simultaneously, then use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My code is working as expected now. Obviously, I have a lot more reading to do...

Answer (score 0):

Joachim Pileborg is right; you have undefined behavior. Be sure to understand why this is, as these mistakes tend to plague new C++ programmers.

Another thing that might mess you up: that `generateRandomGenes(int)` function. If it is creating a new random number generator each time, and that generator is seeded with system time (probably in milliseconds), then it is possible that this loop iterates quickly enough that for consecutive times that `generateRandomGenes(int)` is called, the system clock reads the same time down to the millisecond, and the random number generator is seeded with the same seed each time, thus returning the same "random" number. To fix this, make the random number generator a static variable so it stays in memory, as opposed to getting re-seeded with each use.